# Looking for a prj file NAD_1983_(CSRS)_v7_UTM_Zone_20N

Tags: nad83, prj

I am looking for a prj file for ***NAD_1983_(CSRS)_v7_UTM_Zone_20N***. Anyone out there with one?

Comment: A well known search engine gave this hit with search phrase "NAD_1983_(CSRS)_v7_UTM_Zone_20N" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Esri/projection-engine-db-doc/master/gdal/esri_extra.wkt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this CRS on [epsg.io/2961](https://epsg.io/2961) and you can copy or download in a number of different formats.

> ESRI Well Known Text
>
> ```
> PROJCS["NAD_1983_CSRS_UTM_Zone_20N",
>     GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983_CSRS",
>         DATUM["D_North_American_1983_CSRS",
>             SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
>         PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
>         UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
>     PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
>     PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
>     PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
>     PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-63.0],
>     PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
>     PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
>     UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
> ```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).